# Why is my EJS tag making functions in the script tag undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

In a .ejs file, the ejs code makes the functions in my script tag undefined.

This is the EJS output:

```
<html>
    
    <div style="float: left;" onclick="menuIcon(this)"><button style="width: 25px; height: 25px;">
    
    
    
    <script>
      var prodArray = [object Object]; 
    function menuIcon(x){
        
        x.classList.toggle("change");
       
       
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

This is the .ejs:

```
   <html>
    
<div style="float: left;" onclick="menuIcon(this)"><button style="width: 25px; height: 25px;">



<script>
  var prodArray = <%=prodSchema%>; 
function menuIcon(x){
    
    x.classList.toggle("change");
   
   
}
</script>
</html>
```

This is the node:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/styles"));

const prodSchema = {
    image: "String",
    name: "String",
    price: "Number",
    tag: "String"
}

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 
        
        res.render(__dirname+'/landing_page.ejs', {prodSchema});
    
    
})
app.listen(3001, function(){
    
})
```

Adding the line  `var prodArray = <%=prodSchema%>;` makes the chrome console return an error that `menuIcon()` function is undefined when trying to use the HTML element that it is assigned to: `(index):29 Uncaught ReferenceError: menuIcon is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick ((index):29:52)`

Put simply, it makes the function dysfunctional.

It tried writing the problematic line of code in another script tag, but it makes the variable `prodArray` undefined when trying to use it in another script tag. To solve that problem, I tried using jQuery and other ways of declaring and assigning the variable like `let`, still nothing seems to work. The objective here is declaring and assigning the prodArray variable. Am I using the wrong EJS? Why is the function undefined? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**EDIT**

Using the code above I tried stringifying `prodArray`. First I changed `prodSchema` into an array of objects to replicate the data structure returned by mongoose:

```
const prodSchema = [{
    image: "String",
    name: "String",
    price: "Number",
    tag: "String"
}, {
    image: "String",
    name: "String",
    price: "Number",
    tag: "String"
}]
```

After I changed `prodSchema` into an array of arrays containing objects to match Quentin's output:

```
var array = [];
prodSchema.forEach(element=>{array.push([element])})
```

Then I passed `array` and stringified in the ejs file:

```
var prodArray = <%=JSON.stringify(array)%>;
```

The stringified array is output looks like this:

```
[[{&#34;image&#34;:&#34;String&#34;,&#34;name&#34;:&#34;String&#34;,&#34;price&#34;:&#34;Number&#34;,&#34;tag&#34;:&#34;String&#34;}],[{&#34;image&#34;:&#34;String&#34;,&#34;name&#34;:&#34;String&#34;,&#34;price&#34;:&#34;Number&#34;,&#34;tag&#34;:&#34;String&#34;}]];
```

There are two errors in the chrome console. One is an unexpected token error:

```
(index):8 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'
```

It gives this error for the ampersand in the stringified array.

The other error is the aforementioned one with the button and the menuIcon() function:

```
(index):3 Uncaught ReferenceError: menuIcon is not defined
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick ((index):3:56)
```

My JS:

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.use(express.static(__dirname+"/styles"));

const prodSchema = [{
    image: "String",
    name: "String",
    price: "Number",
    tag: "String"
}, {
    image: "String",
    name: "String",
    price: "Number",
    tag: "String"
}]

app.get('/', function(req, res){

var array = [];
prodSchema.forEach(element=>{array.push([element])})
console.log(array)

        res.render(__dirname+'/test2.ejs', {array});
    
    
})
app.listen(3002, function(){

});
```

My EJS:

```
<html>
    
    <div style="float: left;" onclick="menuIcon(this)"><button style="width: 25px; height: 25px;">
    
    
    
    <script>
      var prodArray = <%=JSON.stringify(array)%>; 
    function menuIcon(x){
        
        x.classList.toggle("change");
       
       
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Am I supposed to do something before stringifying?

Comment: Can you show the raw output from EJS? Hard to help without a [mcve] and seeing what `prodList` and your HTML looks like. It's also good to take a step back and explain what your app is and what you're trying to achieve, because you may be walking into an [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676) where injecting a data structure like this might not even be a particularly great solution approach. Thanks.

Comment: The EJS runs just fine. It is just that a chrome error arises when you attempt to use html elements like buttons that are assigned to the functions. I will add those now.

Comment: Exactly--that's why the output from the EJS is important. That's the thing that has the syntax error. Without seeing that output or the input going into EJS, it's pretty hard to infer what the logical problem with the EJS is.

Comment: I have added the example, my html and the EJS. Thanks.

Comment: There's the error, `var prodArray = [object Object];`. You're going to need to transform your object structure into a string that works as valid JS syntax. Quentin already showed you how to do that with `JSON.stringify(prodArray)`, so if that's not working, then there must be some code you haven't shared yet.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Prod.find({}, function(err, products){
>     res.render(__dirname+'/landing_page.ejs', {prodList: products});
> })
> ```

I'm not too familiar with mongodb, but I'm pretty sure `products` is going to be an array of objects.

[Hmm, it isn't, but it can be converted to one](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/find/).

```
Prod.find({}).toArray(function(err, products) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.render(__dirname+'/landing_page.ejs', {prodList: products});
})
```

So this:

> ```
> var prodArray = <%=prodList%>;
> ```

… is going to generate something like:

```js
var prodArray = [[object Object], [object Object], [object Object]];
```

… which should throw a syntax error that appears before *Uncaught ReferenceError: menuIcon is not defined at HTMLDivElement.onclick* which you quoted.

**Deal with the first error first** since subsequent errors are often knock on effects.

This should have been fairly obvious if you had looked at the output from the EJS as ggorlen advised you to do 12 hours ago.

---

To turn a JS data structure into JS source code (providing it only consists of the core JS data types that are also found in JSON) use `JSON.stringify`:

```
var prodArray = <%=JSON.stringify(prodList)%>;
```

Comment: I already tried using stringify. It still returns the same error.

Comment: Then follow ggorlen's advice

Comment: Also using the EJS tag without stringify works provided it is outside of the script tag.

Comment: Follow ggorlen's advice. Provide a real [mcve].

Comment: If you copy the code there, you can test it.

Comment: @YohannesTimket — No, I can't. I don't have your database. You're the one asking for free help. Read [ask]. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ok, sorry. I have passed a simple object and replicated the error. Thank you.

Comment: Your edit still doesn't show us the generated output from the EJS.

Comment: Would that be the value of prodSchema?

Comment: What the theoretical value of it doesn't really matter. Load the page in your browser. View the source code that was sent to the browser. (And I do mean the source code, not the DOM inspector). Copy. Paste. Reduce it to a [mcve].

Comment: Re edit: Oh look. It says `[object Object]` almost exactly like I said. It's just a single one instead of an array, but it is still a JS syntax error and you need to convert the object you have on the server to JS source code before printing it into the `<script>` element you send to the browser. `JSON.stringify` usually takes care of that unless there is something extra you need to do to get the data out of a monogodb result.

Comment: *Glances at the documentation* oh, it doesn't give you a simple array. Goes to update answer.

Comment: Adding JSON.stringify to the tag in the example returns the same error.

Comment: Should I post the EJS output with the JSON.stringify added?

Comment: No, see my previous comment and the edit I made to the answer after 30 seconds with the docs.

Comment: Sorry if I was unfamiliar with most of the technical jargon and procedures to ask a question.

Comment: If I am understanding the concept correctly, we change the object into an array in order to make it a data type accepted by JSON so that we may change it into JS source code?

Comment: Yes. That's right.

Comment: I tried changing the products into an array and stringifying in the EJS, this gives an ```Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'```. I tried using the button anyway but I still get the same menuIcon() is undefined error. I also tried the stringifying with the reproducible example and it is the same case.